# What a magnificent body, how I should like to see it on the dissecting table

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence from a translation Ivan Turgenev's [Fathers and Sons](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/594046-what-a-magnificent-body-how-i-should-like-to-see) grammatically correct?

> What a magnificent body, how I should like to see it on the dissecting table.

The *how I should like* part sounds a bit non-English to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usage of *how I should like* sounds slightly archaic to a native ear; it belongs more in verse or oratory than in casual speech. It's basically used to mean "I would really like."

Compare, for example, a quote from Pope Francis: "Oh, how I would like a poor Church, and for the poor." This could be rephrased as "I would like a poor Church that is for the poor."

The only thing that needs fixing in your sentence is the comma splice. The comma should be either a semicolon or a period.

Answer (score 1):

It's correct, although such usage is a bit out-dated.

*I should like* = *I would like*